# What is JDBC counterpart of Postgres' "\connect" command?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to execute following Postgres 9.6 commands over JDBC connection

```
CREATE USER my_db WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'my_db';
CREATE DATABASE my_db;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE my_db TO my_db;

\connect my_db; -- THIS ONE FAILS
SET ROLE my_db;

CREATE SCHEMA my_db AUTHORIZATION my_db;
```

"\connect" command fails as not recognized. Is there way to connect other database staying within the same JDBC connection?

UPD: "CONNECT TO ..." and "EXEC SQL CONNECT TO ..." also fail.

Comment: The documentation should help you: [Connecting to the DB over JDBC](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html)

Comment: Did you notice that I already have JDBC connection?

Comment: How could I notice that when you haven't shared any JDBC / Java code? It is also unclear to me what you're attempting to do here.

Comment: Having fresh server and 'postgres' superuser, I want to create another database and schema within this new database staying within the same JDBC connection. I know it is possible to do it using two subsequent JDBC connections. However, it is not the option for me

Comment: Opening a new connection is the **only** way you can do this.

Comment: Have you tried [Connection#setCatalog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setCatalog(java.lang.String))?

Comment: I haven't. Actually, if Posgres JDBC driver can change catalog on-fly then it sends some command. What does it send? I would like to put this command to my script :)

Comment: Actually, `setCatalog` appears to have no effect in PostgreSQL JDBC. Seems to be confirmed [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.LNX.4.30.0107131835350.677-100000%40peter.localdomain). I suspect that @a_horse_with_no_name is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backslash commands are not PostgreSQL SQL commands, they're commands in the `psql` command-line utility. Behind the scenes, `\connect` just closes the connection and opens a new one.

PostgreSQL its self does not have any way to switch databases on a connection.

Disconnect and reconnect to the other DB.